# Jenkins Declarative or scripted pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy

Before we write our jenkinsfile for ci/cd pipeline, should I start with a declarative pipeline or scripted pipeline?  are there limitations to declarative pipeline which could prove to be a blocker later on?

Comment: Depends on what your requirements are and what you believe to be a blocker, hard to answer your question without some context

Comment: I have to write a pipeline for end to end  delivery starting from getting source code from git , build using build tools(maven, gradle), code quality(sonarqube), unit test (junit), getting secrets from vault, deploy to aws cloud environment, regression tests, generate test reports and documentation.

Comment: I'd start with reading this https://e.printstacktrace.blog/jenkins-scripted-pipeline-vs-declarative-pipeline-the-4-practical-differences/

Comment: You can use script{...} step within declarative as a get out of jail card if you need the extra flexibility of scripted